# ubuntu 16.04 freezes with 100% cpu most of which is IOWAIT

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, freeze

My Lenovo Thinkpad Edge 15 0301 running Ubuntu 16.04.5 regularly freezes with System Monitor showing full cpu use, but most of which is IOWAIT.  After a while the system 'gets going' again, but if I reboot while the freeze is still on then the file system is corrupted and I need to run fsck at boot time.  The laptop has an Intel Core i5, 2 cores, hyper threaded and 8 GB memory, 480GB SSD

My other laptop is a HP ProBook 450 G2, but never freezes like that.  It also runs Ubuntu 16.04.5 with comparable hardware: Intel Core i3, 2 cores, hyper threaded and 8 GB memory, 480GB SSD.

Turning off hyper threading on the Lenovo system makes no difference.

How do I determine whether the problem is software or hardware?

Comment: You need to find out what process is causing the blocking IOWAIT’s. Try running [atop](https://www.atoptool.nl) to find this out. My suspicion is that Ubuntu is waiting for disk or network data. Is your SSD healthy or heavily fragmented?

Comment: The ssd is two weeks old, 19.5% full, newly installed OS, self-tests report okay, both short and extended.

Comment: Also see [this question and its answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094486/iowait-cpu-usage-excessively-high) for further reference.

Comment: @agtoever, disk usage is mostly by thunderbird, firefox, jbd2, insync and compiz  I think thunderbird causes most freezes, in particular when I look around in several folders in short order.

Comment: Do you have large local mailbox files (eg >> 1 GB)? What format is your mailbox files? Try to [rebuild your mail database](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/rebuilding-global-database) (backup first!!!)...

Comment: @agtoever the freezing laptop had 1Gb swap, the other had 8.3Gb swap.  After I enlarged the swap as per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq the laptop doesn't freeze any more.      The problem was caused by the installer (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/partman-auto/+bug/1767299)

Comment: Good that you found it. You should post it as an answer and accept it. Maybe you will help others with it.

Answer (score 0):

The freezing laptop had 1Gb swap, the other had 8.3Gb swap. After I enlarged the swap as per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq the laptop doesn't freeze any more. The problem was caused by the installer (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/partman-auto/+bug/1767299)